# How to loop through (and copy) the same data based on number of listbox entries

Tags: excel, vba

I have a userform for an equipment loan checkout which I am trying to make function for multiple items when needed. Essentially, the code below is written so that all the relevant information is correctly transferred to the appropriate sheet, however it only copies the last selected listbox entry.

As I am still quite new to coding in general, I need some help with the loop to do this. But, it seems even more complicated to me, because I want the the date value, name value, return date value, and induction (yes/no) value all copied multiple times into each new table entry - which, is obviously for each item in the list box.

(disregard the mysentence public function at the end).

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

```
Private Sub cmdCheckout_Click()
Dim mysentence As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer
Dim table_list_object As ListObject
Dim table_object_row As ListRow
Dim fnd As Variant

Set ws = Worksheets("Loans")
Set ws2 = Worksheets("MajorInventoryList")
Set table_list_object = ws.ListObjects(1)
Set table_object_row = table_list_object.ListRows.Add
Set fnd = ws2.Range("A:A").Find(Me.ItemList.Column(0, i))

  For i = 0 To Me.ItemList.ListCount - 1

        If Me.ItemList.Selected(i) = True Then

    table_object_row.Range(1, 1).Value = DateValue(Format(Me.txtdate.Value, "dd/mm/yy"))
    table_object_row.Range(1, 2).Value = Me.cboName.Value
    table_object_row.Range(1, 3).Value = Me.ItemList.Column(1, i)
    table_object_row.Range(1, 6).Value = Me.ItemList.Column(2, i)
    table_object_row.Range(1, 8).Value = Me.txtLocation.Value
    table_object_row.Range(1, 9).Value = DateValue(Format(Me.txtReturn.Value, "dd/mm/yy"))
    table_object_row.Range(1, 10).Value = Me.cboInduct.Value
    table_object_row.Range(1, 12).Value = Me.ItemList.Column(0, i)

        If Not fnd Is Nothing Then

            table_object_row.Range(1, 4).Value = fnd.Offset(0, 3).Value
            table_object_row.Range(1, 5).Value = fnd.Offset(0, 4).Value
            table_object_row.Range(1, 7).Value = fnd.Offset(0, 7).Value

            End If

       End If

    Next

mysentence = UpdateAvailability(Me.ItemList)


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a shot. See comments for notes on my modifications.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub cmdCheckout_Click()

    Dim mysentence As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim table_list_object As ListObject
    Dim table_object_row As ListRow
    Dim fnd As Variant

    Set ws = Worksheets("Loans")
    Set ws2 = Worksheets("MajorInventoryList")
    Set table_list_object = ws.ListObjects(1)

      For i = 0 To Me.ItemList.ListCount - 1

            If Me.ItemList.Selected(i) = True Then

                Set table_object_row = table_list_object.ListRows.Add '~~~ Moved this inside loop since you only want to add a row if the list item is selected
                Set fnd = ws2.Range("A:A").Find(Me.ItemList.Column(0, i)) '~~~ and only want to find if item is selected

                With table_object_row '~~~ with block speeds up processing and easier to read

                    .Range(1, 1).Value = DateValue(Format(Me.txtdate.Value, "dd/mm/yy"))
                    .Range(1, 2).Value = Me.cboName.Value
                    .Range(1, 3).Value = Me.ItemList.Column(1, i)
                    .Range(1, 6).Value = Me.ItemList.Column(2, i)
                    .Range(1, 8).Value = Me.txtLocation.Value
                    .Range(1, 9).Value = DateValue(Format(Me.txtReturn.Value, "dd/mm/yy"))
                    .Range(1, 10).Value = Me.cboInduct.Value
                    .Range(1, 12).Value = Me.ItemList.Column(0, i)

                    If Not fnd Is Nothing Then

                        .Range(1, 4).Value = fnd.Offset(0, 3).Value
                        .Range(1, 5).Value = fnd.Offset(0, 4).Value
                        .Range(1, 7).Value = fnd.Offset(0, 7).Value

                    End If

                End With

           End If

        Next

    mysentence = UpdateAvailability(Me.ItemList)

End Sub
```

Comment: That's brilliant! I was somewhat close! Thanks a lot!